# ADT vs Either vs Exceptions

Tags: scala, adt, for-comprehension, either

So, the current implementation uses twitter's `Future` along with throwing exceptions to signal invalid use-case along with `for-comprehensions`, like so:

```
def someMethod(a: ...): Future[X] = {
  // do something
  // if something goes wrong throw exception
  throw new Exception("Certificate not issued")
}

// in some other method, where exceptions break the loop and exit
def someOtherMethod(a: ...): Future[Y] = {
  for {
    x <- someMethod(...)
    y <- yetAnotherMethod(...) // which throws another exception
  } yield y
}
```

The general idea being, when something goes wrong, an exception gets thrown, which will cause exit from the `for-comprehension` block. 
I want to get away from throwing exceptions. One way to solve it is, returning `Either[Error, X]`, and the other way `ADT` using `sealed trait`. So, instead of throwing an `Exception` you can return `Left(Error)` or an `ADT` like `case object NoCertificate extends CertificateResponse`.

Question is: Can I keep the existing for loops intact, if I replace the methods which currently has `throw Exception` with `Either` or `ADT`?

For sake of completeness, here's how I would code my `Either` and `ADT`:

```
sealed trait Error
case object CertificateError extends Error
case object SomeOtherError extends Error

def someMethod(a: ...): Future[Either[Error, CertificateResponse]] = {
  // returns Left(CertificateError) or Right(CertificateResponse)
}
```

OR

```
sealed trait CertificateResponse
case class Certificate(x509) extends CertificateResponse
case object NoCertificate extends CertificateResponse

def someMethod(a: ...): Future[CertificateResponse] = {
  // returns NoCertificate or Certificate(X509)
}
```

will either of these alternative solution (to throwing exceptions and breaking referential transparency), work with `for-comprehensions`? Will the negative response: `Left()` or `NoCertificate` automagically exit the `for-comprehension` block? If not, how to make it, such that I can keep the `for-comprehension` blocks as is? Something akin to `cats EitherT's leftMap`?

Please Note: We cannot use `cats` Monad Transformer like `EitherT` (which has `leftMap` which signals exit conditions), as that is not one of the libraries we use in our stack. Sorry!

Thanks!

Comment: Scalaz also includes an `EitherT`, is that library an option? Because really, the behaviour you're specifying is _precisely_ what using a monad transformer gets you, and if you can't use libraries then you'll have to code one by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd really look into whether some library offering a monad transformer is a possibility (`Scalaz` also includes one), because this is exactly the use case they're for. If it's really not possible, your only alternative is writing your own - meaning, create some class which can wrap your method outputs that has `map` and `flatMap` methods that do what you want. This is doable for both the Either and the ADT-based solution. The Either-based one would look a little like this:

```
sealed trait Error

case object CertificateError extends Error
case object SomeOtherError extends Error

case class Result[+T](value: Future[Either[Error, T]]) {
  def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) : Result[S] = {
    Result(value.map(_.map(f)))
  }

  def flatMap[S](f: T => Result[S])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) : Result[S] = {
    Result {
      value.flatMap {
        case Left(error) => Future.successful(Left(error))
        case Right(result) => f(result).value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(You 100% need this sort of wrapping class! There's no way of getting a return type `Future[ADT]` or `Future[Either[Error, Result]]` to behave in the way you want because it would require altering the way `Future` works.)

With the code as above, you can use `for`-comprehensions over `Result` types and they'll automagically exit if either their containing `Future` fails or the `Future` succeeds with an `Error` as you specified. Silly example:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def getZero() : Result[Int] = Result(Future.successful(Right(0)))

def error() : Result[Unit] = Result(Future.successful(Left(SomeOtherError)))

def addTwo(int: Int) : Result[Int] = Result(Future.successful(Right(2 + int)))

val result = for {
  zero <- getZero()
  _ <- error()
  two <- addTwo(zero)
} yield two

Await.result(result.value, 10.seconds) // will be `Left(SomeOtherError)`
```

The reason I strongly recommend an existing `EitherT` transformer is because they come with *a ton* of utility methods and logic that will make your life significantly easier, but if it's not an option, it's not an option.